# How to create a site using SFRA but name and ID would be my custom name and ID

Tags: demandware

Whenever I am creating a site following the steps in SFCC infocentre I am getting two sites with name as RefArch and RefArchGlobal but I want my site with my id and my name, I was able to do that by creating a custom site and then assigning the same catalog as RefArch and also the same content libraries as RefArch and then by importing the slot config of Refarch to my custom site, I want to know if there is any other way of doing it easily.

Thanks,
Faizen

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you can make use of the Site Import/Export feature.

https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/content/b2c_commerce/topics/import_export/b2c_site_import_export.html?resultof=%22%53%69%74%65%22%20%22%73%69%74%65%22%20%22%69%6d%70%6f%72%74%22%20

It will provide you with a ZIP representation of the sites. In these files, you can manipulate the IDs and names.